# how to change font direction inside styles.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, styles

i have Language changhing buttons and i want to set font direction in styles.xml also for each Language .

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

how to do that ?

Comment: Are you talking about left-to-right / right-to-left in text boxes? P.s. if so, check this blog: http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: just TextView's text . so "!" or "." for example will be in the right side

Answer (score 0):

This would set the direction of your text in the styles.xml, but it has to be done in every button

`android:textDirection=""`

Comment: this cant be applied to all layouts ? no just button ? if so , how

Comment: You can also set the `android:textDirection=""` in <textView></textView>